# How to convert to JSONObject

Tags: javascript, extjs

[image]Below code:

```
grid.getStore().getAt(0).data.ServiceDetails
```

Output:

```
"{brief: {"totalBilledUser":3}, details:{"totalBilledUser":3, "totalBilledUser1":3, "totalBilledUser2":3, "totalBilledUser3":3, "totalBilledUser4":3, "totalBilledUser5":3}}"
```

Please note that here the output starts with **double quote**.

1. ```
   JSON.parse(grid.getStore().getAt(0).data.ServiceDetails);
   ```

   output Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token b in JSON at position 1
2. ```
   JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(grid.getStore().getAt(0).data.ServiceDetails))
   ```

   It returns original string back.
   Please guide me the proper way to get it as JSON object.

Comment: The data that you have is not valid JSON so you are not going to be able to parse it like that.

Comment: attached Image please guide how to make it as JSON Object

Answer (score 1):

the quotes are the problem, take a look:

`"{ brief: { "totalBilledUser": 3 } }"`

The first `"` marks the beginning of the string, but the second `"` instead of open the strinf for `totalBilledUser`, closes the first `"`.

Possible solutions are:

1. Open and close the output with single quotation marks `'`.

   ```
   '{ brief: { "totalBilledUser": 3 } }'
   ```
2. Escape the double quotes inside the output:

   ```
   "{ brief: { \"totalBilledUser\": 3 } }"
   ```

Once you achieve one of the above solutions, you'll have, at least, a valid string. Now you can use `JSON.stringify` and then `JSON.parse` to transform it into JSON format. Hope I make myself clear.

Comment: attached Image please guide how to make it as JSON Object